# Translate multi-touch events to regular mouse events in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse

The "Pen and Touch" utility in the Windows 7 control panel allows to map some touch events to normal mouse events, for example a long "click" (touch) to right-button click. The mapping is done globally, not at the application level.

I would like to translate the movement of two fingers to mouse wheel events. My touch screen supports up to two fingers. The mapping should be done globally, as mentioned above. Is there any external tool that allows to do that?